Shifting from Google Collab to Jupyter Notebook
I have a jupyter widget app written fully in google collab. I want to run the same program through jupyter notebook.
I tried downloading the collab notebook as .ipnyb and opening it through jupyter, but there are certain google collab specific functions such as files.upload(), mount drive, exportToDrive(). How to overcome this errors?

In Google Colab notebooks one can use Colab-specific libraries such as files that cannot be used in other environments.
This is the snippet of code that I usually include in my notebooks
import sys
isColab = 'google.colab' in sys.modules
if isColab:
     # do Colab-specific stuff
     from google.colab import files

For the Colab-specific stuff you will either skip it or find a workaround.
Alternatively, you can run Google Colab with a local runtine using Docker with a Colab image, see: https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html.
See also the Github discussion.
About the Google Colab environment:
Google Colaboratory notebooks run on virtual machines with Ubuntu Jammy operating system.
import distro
distro.info()

{'id': 'ubuntu',
 'version': '22.04',
 'version_parts': {'major': '22', 'minor': '04', 'build_number': ''},
 'like': 'debian',
 'codename': 'jammy'}

The Ubuntu machine comes with a few libraries pre-installed, some of them are specific to the Colab environment. You can view them with:
%pip list
[...]
google-auth
google-colab

Among them is for instance the library google.colab for uploading/downloading files
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()


Minor thing: Could you instead encourage use of the magic variation %pip list. Google Colab recently added support for %pip despite being a fork of a now outdated fork of Jupyter. So use of the better magic %pip is essentially universal now and users will have a better experience everywhere not using the exclamation point in conjucntion with pip any longer in the modern Jupyter ecosystem.

thanks for the observation @Wayne! Actually in Google Colab and also in IPython (I just tested it) one can also simply type pip ... like for some other commands like ls, no need to escape with a ! or use magics

True, and because of automagics is the default usually, the magic variation gets applied. However, explicit is always better.
